# On DST(America/Los_Angeles), if i add one day it adds only 23 hours instead of 24

Tags: java, dst

Here is the sample code

```
public class DateFormatSampleCode {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles"));
        cal.setTime(sdf.parse("2016-03-12T02:00:00-0800"));
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles"));
        System.out.println(sdf.format(cal.getTime()));
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        System.out.println(sdf.format(cal.getTime()));  
    }
}
```

Here the Answer is

> "2016-03-12T01:00:00-0800"

, but from my point of view it should be "

> 2016-03-12T03:00:00-0700

".

Comment: What if you re-set the timezone after you've added the day? Also, I'd recommend `java.time` rather than using `Calendar`.

Comment: @OleV.V.: Thanks, Till Java 7 we can add hours instead of days. From java8 we have ZonedDateTime and LocalDateTime.

Comment: General best practice. For Java 8, use `java.time`. For Java <=7, use [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/). Trying to work around the edge cases that led to the necessity of these improvements is just not worth your time, IMHO.

Comment: @OleV.V. - lol.  too many languages! :) Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

As you know, “During 2016, daylight saving time (DST) is in effect from March 13, 2016 at 2 a.m. (local time) to November 6, 2016 at 2 a.m. (local time)” (https://www.nist.gov/pml/time-and-frequency-division/popular-links/daylight-saving-time-dst). So if you add 24 hours to March 12 2am, you hit exactly the time when clocks are moved forward from 2 to 3 am. So I don’t think it’s crystal clear what result to expect. I would immediately expect either `02:00:00-0800` or `03:00:00-0700` (the latter is what you expected).

You are using the pre-Java-8 `Calendar` class. If the result is documented precisely, I have missed it. The doc only says the addition is “based on the calendar's rules”. Thinking about it, the problem is what to expect if you start from a time between 2 and 3 on March 12. Before 2 you just get the same time on March 13, 24 hours later. After 3 is also easy, you get the same time, only it is 23 hours later because of the change. For times between 2 and 3, the same time does not exist on March 13, so a choice has to be made. It seems the choice has been to subtract one hour. They’ve furthermore chosen to do this also for 2:00:00 am, but not for 3:00:00 so to make the rule valid for a half-open interval of one hour. At least that is consistent. We probably cannot completely avoid unexpected results.

The Java 8 `java.time` classes like for example `ZonedDateTime` are better documented and hence more reliable. `ZonedDateTime.plusDays()`, for example, adds day/s to a local date-time and converts back to `ZonedDateTime`. If the local date-time is in a gap (as here), it “will be adjusted forward by the length of the gap” (here 1 hour). So your result will be `2016-03-13T03:00-07:00[America/Los_Angeles]`, exactly as you had expected.

One possible lesson to learn is, use the `java.time` classes if you can use Java 8.